# vimdiff and MacVim

Tags: vim, macvim, vimdiff

I'd like to run vimdiff on MacVim. Is there an easy way I'd be able to do it?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

- From the terminal

If you have the `mvim` script installed (it is in the dmg, just put it somewhere in your `PATH`), you can just type in a shell:

```
mvim -d file1 file2
```

You can alias this to mvimdiff if you like.

- From within macvim

In macvim, like in vim , you can also use:

```
:e file1
:diffsplit file2
or
:vert diffsplit file2
```

The second option gives you a vertical diff, which is usually more readable

Answer (score 10):

If you symlink gvimdiff to mvim then mvim will start with -d etc.  Vim and Mvim both look at what executable name they've been started with to determine how they behave.  That how gvim and vim can be both the same executable on linux and it's the same on OSX.

Comment: That didn't work for me. I got this error: "The diff tool gvimdiff is not available as 'gvim'".

Comment: @Raffi - A lot can change in 2 years, it was good advice at the time.

Comment: @Benj Ah I didn't notice the date :). Any ideas on how to get this going?

Comment: @R --- `vimdiff file1.txt file2.txt` does (if you run it from the terminal, so not MacVim a la OP).  I think it's there by default.  I usually use MacVim, but go to the term to diff in vim.  It's VIm, so terming it isn't a big deal, right? ;^)

Comment: For MacVim you want to symlink it to mvimdiff.  While in MacVim type :help mvim for more details.

Answer (score 10):

Ok. I have kindof answered my own comment:

To diff two open buffers in vim, open them vertically, and select the first and type `:diffthis` then the second one and type `:diffthis` again.

This works for more than two buffers too =)

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me on mac. I am using MacVim snapshot 72:

```
 /Applications/MacVim.app/Contents/MacOS/Vim -d -g path_to_file1 path_to_file2
```

It works exactly like gvimdiff on windows.

Update: It even works with 3 files. This command will split the screen 3-ways and let you do a 3-way diff in macvim:

```
 /Applications/MacVim.app/Contents/MacOS/Vim -d -g path_to_file1 path_to_file2 path_to_file3
```